# Integrals such as x+y wrt x

Tags: calculus, integration

This question is in lieu of "Integrating $dψ=(x+y)dx+x_0dy$". Though I got good answers, none of them could explain the real question. Consider the integral,

$\int(x+y)dx$

In a book I recently read, such an integral is equated to $\frac{x^2}{2} + xy$, i.e. they treat x and y as constants wrt each other. However, there is no explicit mention of any dependence of x and y in the context, son naturally, you take them to functions of each other, right? But they treat (I am ignoring that it is a definite integral at the moment-unless the definiteness of the integral allows you to evaluate it )

$\int(x+y)dx = \int xdx + \int ydx$ = $x^2/2 + xy$,

i.e. they treat y as a constant wrt x in the 2nd integral. But why?
      can you do that for any integral? For example, can you say

$\int xy dx=y\int x dx = x^2y/2 +C$ ????

I am utterly confused, as this( integral of x+y) is what they have done in the book (pg 333 mathematical methods for physicists) for similar integrals. And again, I DON'T want to SOLVE the ODE, I merely used it as an example to see the applications of aforementioned integrals which confuse me.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

When you are calculating the integral of $f(x, y)$ with respect to $x$, the intuition is that you are summing the infinitely many $f(x, y)\cdot dx$ infinitesimals as $x$ goes through all of the values in a range but $y$ is static. Thus $x$ is the "variable" and $y$, as far as the integral is concerned, is a "constant".

This doesn't mean that $y$ is an unchanging value, $y$ may be as variable as $x$ is. It just means that $y$ is unchanging throughout the infinite sum.

If $x$ and $y$ are dependent however, the integral is taken as over $f(x, y(x))$ as $x$ changes.

Comment: So if I have any integrand as an expression involving x and y's integrated wrt x(or y), I can take y(or x) as a constant in that integral? Any proof/reference?

Comment: What about the 2nd example?

Comment: Yes. My proof is the definition of $\int \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. As a reference, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Formal_definitions should be sufficient.

EDIT: The 2nd example is correct.

Comment: So, on the whole, expressions such as $\int y dx$ ARE integrable...as long as the integrand is a function of both x and y, right?

Comment: Yes. In the case of $\int \, y \, \mathrm{d}x$ the function is $f(x) = y$, which with respect to $x$ is the constant function. I wouldn't call the integrand a function of $x$ and $y$ however, because the integral "recognizes" it as simply a function of $x$. In particular, $\int \, \mathrm{d}x = \int \, 1 \, \mathrm{d}x = x + C$, which is the integral of $f(x) = 1$.