# How to integrate a multi-variable function like this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$\varphi = \int\frac{-cx}{x^2 + y^2}\,\mathrm dx + \int\frac{cy}{x^2 + y^2}\,\mathrm dy$$

I mean is there anything like partial integration as partial differentiation? Should I consider $x$ as a constant or variable while integrating with respect to $\,\mathrm dy$? This blows away my mind. How to solve this?

Comment: You are correct. Treat $y$ as a constant when integrating w.r.t. $x$. Similarly, treat $x$ as a constant when integrating w.r.t. $y$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrals such as x+y wrt x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955431/integrals-such-as-xy-wrt-x)

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot